# Bootstrap modal doesn´t show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker

I´m getting crazy with this. I change the libraries order in every way and there must be some conflict between jquery ui and bootstrap js libraries. I add fullcalendar inside a dialog, but when I select some day in the calendar, datetimepicker is not shown ($(.modal).modal('show') doesn´t work). There is no js warnings.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-iso.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lang/es.js'></script>
<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
        dialogHorario = $( "#dialogHorario" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 600,
            modal: true
        });

        // Evento click para mostrar un dialogo modal para editar el horario
        $( ".editarHorario" ).on( "click", function() {
            // Para evitar que el diálogo se cierre precipitadamente
            event.preventDefault();

            // asignaturaId es el parámetro que hemos pasado a través del link editar
            var asignaturaId = this.id;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month'
                },
                navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                weekends: false,
                select: function(start, end) {
                    // Display the modal.
                    // You could fill in the start and end fields based on the parameters
                    $('.modal').modal('show');
                },
                eventClick: function(event, element) {
                    // Display the modal and set the values to the event values.
                    $('.modal').modal('show');
                    $('.modal').find('#title').val(event.title);
                    $('.modal').find('#starts-at').val(event.start);
                    $('.modal').find('#ends-at').val(event.end);

                },
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events
            });

            // Bind the dates to datetimepicker.
            // You should pass the options you need
            $("#starts-at, #ends-at").datetimepicker();

            // Whenever the user clicks on the "save" button om the dialog
            $('#save-event').on('click', function() {
                var title = $('#title').val();
                if (title) {
                    var eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: $('#starts-at').val(),
                        end: $('#ends-at').val()
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');

                // Clear modal inputs
                $('.modal').find('input').val('');

                // hide modal
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
            });

            // Quitando el foco
            $.ui.dialog.prototype._focusTabbable = function(){};
            dialogHorario.dialog( "open" );
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialogHorario" title="Horarios de la asignatura" style="display:none;">
    <div class="bootstrap-iso">
        <div id='calendar'></div>
        <div id='datepicker'></div>
        <div id="hola" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" >
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Programar clase</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label class="col-xs-4" for="starts-at">Inicio: </label>
                                <input type="text" name="starts_at" id="starts-at" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <label class="col-xs-4" for="ends-at">Fin</label>
                                <input type="text" name="ends_at" id="ends-at" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">Guardar cambios</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check out the network tab in dev tools (F12) and verify that all of your resources are loading.

Comment: If you can get a working JSFiddle, it'll make this much easier.  Don't think it's the issue, but it's bothering me you're opening the model by referencing the class in jquery ".modal", rather than by id so you don't open multiple or the wrong one.

Comment: Call your code inside the callback of `$(document).on('ready', function(){ // your code... })` maybe it's gonna help you

Comment: I checked resources and everything seems fine. I tried $(document).on('ready', function(){}) and it doesn´t resolve my issue. I´m working in a JSFiddle but it shows some libraries errors.

Comment: Something changed when I added my bootstrap-iso class (bootstrap css compile with less to avoid issues with jquery ui css) into `<div id="hola" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" >`. I can see the modal window but instead I should be seeing a calendar and only when I click in a day this modal window should appear.

Comment: I changed $('.modal') to $('#hola') and modal window now reacts when I click on close button but it isn´t appearing properly yet. It´s fixed to the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: please link us to your JSFiddle then it's easier for us to see what's happening

Comment: BTW please don't use the fullcalendar.io site as a CDN, it's not designed as one and not to be relied on. It's just a website for advertising and documenting the product. It's not scaled for lots of people to keep remotely accessing the JS files. Use CDNJS instead as recommended at https://fullcalendar.io/download. You'll also see this warning if you were to visit, for instance, https://fullcalendar.io/fullcalendar-releases/fullcalendar/2.1.1/lib/

Comment: Finally I got my  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/makelele24/5q92L4bv/). Errors come with css bootstrap library. I don´t know how to make things work correctly. Events and display don´t work OK. Including bootstrap css change all datatables styles.

Comment: I tried to scope bootstrap.min.css to fullcalendar and datetimepicker divs with [less](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) compiling but that css generated file caused my initial problems asked here.